# Ionic Build Failing ANDROID_SDK_VERSION

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build

Getting this Error when I try to build a new project on Ubuntu 16.04, android 6.2.0, node 10.9.0:

> WARNING: The onesignal-gradle-plugin MUST be before
>   com.android.application!    Please put onesignal-gradle-plugin first
>   OR update to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 or newer! The
>   Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to
>   be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.     at
>   build_euiye7k7zv7uafyosqy83rrni.run(/home/paul/Downloads/[project]/platforms/android/build.gradle:143)
>   The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Incremental java compilation
>   is an incubating feature. The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has
>   been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please
>   use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/paul/Downloads/[project]/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 258
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SDK_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.844 secs
Error: /home/paul/Downloads/[project]/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/paul/Downloads/[project]/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 258
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SDK_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

  ```
  cordova run android --release exited with exit code 1.

  Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with ionic 4, did you happen to find a solution?